# Joomla: instantiate ContentModelArticle really slow

Tags: php, mysql, json, joomla

I have a json file of about 50M in size, about 10k records. I am using following code to insert into Joomla programmatically, it works pretty well as all relevant tables get updated simultaneously, e.g., #_assets, however the code runs really slow: about 40 hours passed now but only about 4k articles are processed. Can I speed up the process somehow?

I do know that if I do insert into `#_content`, `#_tags`, etc, it'll be much quicker, but that approach has some trivia complications that I try to avoid.

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );

define('JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR', JPATH_BASE . DS . 'administrator' . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_content');

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');

require_once (JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_content/models/article.php');

$string = file_get_contents("items.json");
$json_str = json_decode($string, true);
foreach($json_str as $row){
$new_article = new ContentModelArticle();
    $data = array(
        'title' => $row['title'][0],
        'alias' => $row['alias'],
        'introtext' => $row['content'],
        'state' => 1,
        'catid' => 8,           /* don't hard code here! */
        'created' => $row['pdate'][0],
        'created_by' => 798,
        'created_by_alias' => $row['poster'][0],
        'publish_up' => $row['pdate'][0],
        'urls' => $row['urls'],
        'access' => 1,
        'metadata' => array(
            'tags' => $row['tags'],
            'robots' => "",
            'author' => implode(" ", $row['poster']),
            'rights' => "",
            'xreference' => "",            
        ),
    );
$new_article->save($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were running this in Joomla as an extension I would suggest turning on debugging and having a look at the `Profile Information` in the `Joomla! Debug Console` to see where allthe time is being spent.

You're not, so the rest is deduction (therefore possibly faulty).

1. You're loading the `ContentModelArticle` for each insert this means that it creates and destroys not only the model class for each row but also the table class for each row.
2. If these are all inserts, then you don't need all the overhead of the model (e.g. checking if the article exists first).
3. If the data is all valid you also don't need the data preparation (`prepareTable()`) in the content model nor the `check()` in the content table.

If you don't need that you could load the `JTable` once, then call the table objects `save()` passing in your array for each article. That will run the `bind()`, `check()`, `store()` — where asset tracking is updated, and complete the insert.

So, you could try something like this, I think it will be faster, not sure by how much.

```
$contentTable = JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable', array());
foreach($json_str as $row){
    $data = array(
        'title' => $row['title'][0],
        'alias' => $row['alias'],
        'introtext' => $row['content'],
        'state' => 1,
        'catid' => 8,           /* don't hard code here! */
        'created' => $row['pdate'][0],
        'created_by' => 798,
        'created_by_alias' => $row['poster'][0],
        'publish_up' => $row['pdate'][0],
        'urls' => $row['urls'],
        'access' => 1,
        'metadata' => array(
        'tags' => $row['tags'],
        'robots' => "",
        'author' => implode(" ", $row['poster']),
        'rights' => "",
        'xreference' => "",            
    ),
    $contentTable->save($data);
}
```

****Disclaimer:*** this isn't tested code it's just out of my head and into the browser.

Comment: Yes, I used JTable to revise my code, with some experiment: 1. it seems like I need to put `$contentTable = JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable', array());` within the foreach loop, or the script will exit after inserting of one row; 2. I still need to explicitly bind(), check(), and store() instead of solely using save(), or the process will still quit early (without errors) after few rows insertion. Don't know how to put code here as SO put limits of characters when I comment. Thanks